Volume of Horned Sphere
Given the formula for the volume of a Torus:

consider the Alexander Horned Sphere as an iterated gluing of torus parts.

assuming then some parameters $\theta$ and $\lambda$ have been fixed for drawing each subsequent level, with radii $R_k$ and $r_k$

Ignoring the contribution of the end bits (for simplicity of calculation, although suggestions are welcome)

The question becomes: if and when (for which values of the parameters) does the volume of this object converge, and what would its formula be?

Well, the volume is bounded above and is monotonically increasing as you add more "branches,"  so it does converge. As to what, well, I haven't the faintest.

Upon closer inspection I think the parameter value $\lambda=3/4$ would have been more reasonable. This parameter along with $\theta$ would help determine the outer radius $R_k$ at each level $k$. Not sure about inner radius, but it's clear $r_k \geq r_{k+1}$. Then there should be $2^k$ times $(2\pi - \theta)$ torus segments of level $k$ with volume $V_k$

Let $V$ be the volume relative to a torus of radii $R, \ r$. Then $\frac{1}{1-2\lambda^3}(\delta-\frac{2\lambda^2 r}{\pi R})\leq V\leq \frac{\delta}{1-2\lambda^3}$, where $\delta=1-\theta/2\pi$
